# Excel dates stored in SQL Table in Decimal format - convert back to dates

Tags: sql-server, power-automate, sql-server-2017

I have a Power Automate flow that is reading from Excel, and is storing date values in a SQL table.

29/03/2023 is being stored as 45014.75, and 17/10/2023 is being stored as 45216.3958333333.

Does anyone know how these values can be converted back to actual dates? I thought I could do something like the below but it errors out.

```
SELECT
    convert(datetime,'45014.75', 103),  --29/03/2023 
    convert(datetime,'45216.3958333333', 103) --17/10/2023
```

Comment: excel uses 18991230 as base date due to *reasons*, so you can do: `select cast(-2 as datetime) + 45216.3958333333
, cast(-2 as datetime) +  45014.75` since sql server uses 19000101

Comment: Perhaps nitpicking, but that is not strictly true, excel uses 01/01/1900 as the base date, but it starts at an ordinal of 1 (if you convert 0 to a date you get the invalid date 00/01/1900), the second deduction is because Excel considers 1900 to be a leap year when it wasn't (for compatibility reasons due a lotus bug), so 29/01/1900 is considered a valid date, and this is why 2. So although unlikely and probably not worth much thought, if you are converting a date in January or February 1900 you would need to use -1 instead of -2 to get the right date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `DateTime Format` to `ISO 8601`, under Advanced Options, in the Excel Power Automate action.

[image]